# Math for calculating radius attacks

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

I am working on implementing the SRD in Python (programming language), but unfortunately I am not great at math.  I am stumped with figuring out how to calculate all of the squares that are within range of a radius (or cone) attack.

I did find [What is a radius on a square grid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19400/what-is-a-radius-on-a-square-grid/19404#19404), which gives a handy formula for calculating the distance between squares (if a given square is within range).  D=√((X * X)+(Y * Y))

I am hoping there are some math whizzes on here that can help me come up with a formula!

grid details:

I am using a simple coordinate system, (x,y) starting with 0 as first row on top and 0 as first column on the left.

Comment: I think this is off topic I'm afraid. You're better off asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths

Comment: @James Lee Vann, how does this question differ from the one you already linked? How do you expect your answers to be different?

Comment: Rasterising a circle is a basic programming question. Try GameDev.SE or StackOverflow. Actually nevermind, here's the Wikipedia article on how it's done: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: @ColinD - I am not looking to find if a single square is in range, but to find all squares that are within range.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie- I am reading the article you linked now, thanks, I guess I just did not know what to look for!  I think that will answer my question once I have read it and understood it :)

Comment: @JamesLeeVann I don't agree with your interpretation of the linked question. However I will offer you this naive approach: Take all points on your grid, then test your equation against each of those points.  This can be simplified to searching an N by N grid where N is the the radius converted into squares.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a radius on a square grid?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19400/what-is-a-radius-on-a-square-grid)

Comment: I'd like to point out that the default assumption is that pre-shaped area templates are used in D&D, rather than calculating the radii by hand each time... not that such a feature couldn't be useful.

Comment: @ColinD Thanks, I have created a rough implementation that takes this approach, I added some optimization so it doesn't check every square, just ones that are close.  However, it still doesn't match the D&D official templates perfectly, not sure if it is a problem with the algorithm or my implementation of it.  Probably close enough for now.

Comment: @JamesLeeVann, Isn't that because D&D 3.5 AoE attacks/spells assume that a diagonal is 1.5 squares, not sqrt(2)=1.414... squares?